# Prevent proxies connect in my dedicated server

Tags: iptables, connections

I have one dedicated server, and I use IPTABLES for firewall. Recently, I received a lot of connections (attacks) using proxies to change IPS, and bypass firewall. Have anything do, for prevent connections by proxies? Any rules in iptables to check if connections provide by proxies?

Thanks,
Caio.

Comment: What do you mean by "using proxies to change IPS"? Can you add information from the logs to the question?

Comment: People send me a lot of connections, to my game. I limited connections per ips, but dind't have effect, because, peolple use proxy to get a "fake" ip, and bypass limitation by firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's is no proper technical way to determine the information that You are trying to get. You might invent some rules in your ip tables, but those will have a very low correlation with the reality. So either you will not catch those you want, or you will get a large number of false positives. Neither can be considered to make sense.